# Extract Message-id from Message Header Grails

Tags: java, email, grails, message

I need message-id of an email from message header,What are the ways to extract message id from message Header.I am using grails mail plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message id is the first element of a mail header. So a way to achieve this is to output the e-mail content in a String and then extract the message-id using a regex (example done in Java but you can do the same using Groovy regex).

```
    String id;
    String mailToString; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Message-ID: <(.*)>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(mailToString);
    if(m.find()){
        id =  m.group();
    }
```

Comment: Can we set status of message as unread at the time of sending email so that it could be seen in sent folder as unread via mail plugin.

Comment: You can set the read/unread flag only if you use IMAP see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Flags.html

Answer (score 0):

@Benoit - it dit not work for me.

instead:

```
def inbox = store.getFolder('INBOX')
inbox.messages.each{email->
   println "Message-Id: ${email.messageID}"
   }
```

did the job perfectly.

The same works also for each Part of a Multipart email.

cheers.